# SSL connect error after Tomcat 8 upgrade

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat8

After upgrading Tomcat from 7 to 8.0.26, we are getting SSL connect error in making an https outbound call from our app.  The destination site uses Thawte certificate and strangely even curl command in the box to that site is failing with SSL connect error after TC8 upgrade.  We don't have ciphers setting in server.xml, so we were using [the default ciphers for the JVM with Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html), and now [Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) is using HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5 by default.  Can the ciphers change cause the SSL connect error in outbound https call or curl command?  We had no problem calling the https call before.

Comment: They surely can, try to run `curl --head -v URL`, that should give you more info about the SSL step.

Comment: Did you upgrade Java too? Or just Tomcat?

Comment: @watery here is what we get: curl -v 'outbound_url'
* About to connect() to outbound_site_com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying (ip)... connected
* Connected to outbound_site_com (ip) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5961
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error

Comment: @Andreas Tomcat only.  Java is on 7.